# Xie-Beni Index: Clusters-Features 1.0.3 python library unavailable in pip install

Tags: python, cluster-analysis, metrics

I am trying to use 'Xie-Beni Index' from the Clusters-Features library available here: https://pypi.org/project/Clusters-Features/ through the following code:

```
pip install Clusters-Features
```

However, I am getting the following error.

> Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://us-python.pkg.dev/colab-wheels/public/simple/

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Clusters-Features==1.0.2 (from versions: none)

> ERROR: No matching distribution found for Clusters-Features==1.0.2

Can you please help me with either of the following:-

(a) How to install this library?

(b) Is there any alternate library having a **Xie-Beni Index** function?

Comment: Question (b) remains unanswered. Pls, answer if you have something to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can [download files](https://pypi.org/project/Clusters-Features/#files) and [Installing from local archives](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-local-archives).

Comment: That's again a good suggestion. Hence accepting.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to install it now (Answer (a)). It is valid for python version >=3.8. Currently, Google Collaboratory provides version 3.7 as default. It is working after the version update to 3.9.